# Swap Windows and Ubuntu partitions

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I bought a new laptop with an SSD and an HDD with Windows 10 installed on the SSD. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on the HDD first, but then I wanted to swap Windows 10 and Ubuntu. First I cloned Windows with EaseUS to the HDD, and then using a live CD removed Windows from the SSD and moved Ubuntu to the SSD. Now Ubuntu works fine, but I can`t load Windows 10.

SSD partitions:

[image: SSD partitions]

HDD partitions:

[image: HDD partitions]

Comment: As you could see from experience, Windoze is not flexible. Did you follow any tutorial to clone it?

Comment: "but I can`t load windows" Not an Ubuntu problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Boot from the Windows 10 DVD or USB and try using the repair utilities. If successful, it will probably make Ubuntu not able to boot anymore, but that is easy to fix.
2. If (1) does not work, or if it does work in making Windows boot, but Ubuntu does not boot, use [boot-repair-disk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/).